# Customizing PHP error messages

Tags: php, sql, error-handling

I want to change the following `PHP` error message so that user does not see this error and I would like to display an error which is more understandable by the user.

For example consider this error which I want to edit,

```
Notice: Undefined index: user_input on line 33
```

I want to display the following error message instead of the above default error message,

```
Process failed
```

How can I implement this on my website?

Comment: Read about exception handling here http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an error it is a notice, so you will need to do few things:

1. First look into [ErrorException](http://php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php) you need to convert the notice to an exception.
2. Catch the exception
3. Print your custom error message

Example:

```
<?php
function exception_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ) {
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline);
}
set_error_handler("exception_error_handler");


try {
    //Trigger exception:
    $my_array = array();
    echo $my_array['undefined'];//Notice will throw exception

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Process failed';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check to see if the variable [is set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) and display the error message you want if it's not